# Improve spreadsheet filtering script performance

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet where first column contains names and next 17 contains 0, 1 or are empty. Every row  looks like this:

```
foobar 0 0 0 1 0 1 // and so on
```

I need to make function, called from menu, that shows the user only rows with `1` in the target column (`arg1`). Here is code:

```
var ssBase = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var last = ssBase.getLastRow() ;
var data = ssBase.getDataRange().getValues();

function SkillsFilter(arg1){

  ssBase.showRows(1, last+1);

  for (var i=1; i < last; i++){
    if (data[i][arg1] != "1"){                         
      ssBase.hideRows(i+1);
}}}
```

This function doesn't perform as fast as I'd like. How should I increase performance? Will cache help me or something else?

Answer (score 2):

You're making many calls to the Spreadsheet services within your `for` loop - if you can change those many operations into one, you'll see a great speed improvement. Read [Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/best_practices) for some background and guidance.

I suggest that you reconsider the approach of hiding & showing various rows of data. Instead, you could display a filtered list, and manipulate that filter using your menu functions. Let's say the data you have looks like this...

[image: Sample Spreadsheet]

On a second tab in the spreadsheet, you could provide the filtered version of your list. The following formula in cell A2 would create a filtered list of data from the orignal data sheet (called "Master" in this example):

```
=filter(Master!A2:R;Master!D2:D="1")
```

To create that filter programmatically, use the `setFormulaR1C1()` function. Here is a function that you could call from your menu items to set the filter for any particular column.

```
/**
 * Sets the filter in cell A2 of the sheet named "Filter" to display
 * only rows with a number 1 in the indicated column.
 *
 * @param {number} column The "skill" column to filter for
 */
function setFilter(column) {
  column = column | 2;  // Use first "skill" column as default
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Filter");
  var formula = "Master!R[0]C[0]:C[17];Master!R[0]C["
       +column
       +"]:C["
       +column
       +"]=1";
  sheet.getRange("A2").setFormulaR1C1(formula);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code will show all rows that contain the number 1, thought the column range:

```
function mySort() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

  // set col and row
  var col = sheet.getLastColumn(), row = sheet.getLastRow()-1;

  // hide all rows
  sheet.hideRows(2, row);   

  // itterate through columns
  for(var k=0; k<col; k++) {
    this.data = sheet.getRange(2, 1, row, col)
      .sort({column: parseInt(k+1), ascending: true}).getValues();

    //set counters
    var cFirst=0, cSecond=0;

    // itterate to find number of "1" rows in column k
    for(var i=0; i<row; i++) {    
      if(this.data[i][k] == 1) {
        cFirst++;
      } else {
        cSecond++;
      }
    }

    // calculate rowIndex
    var rIndex = row-cSecond;

    // show (unhide) only "1" rows
    sheet.showRows(rIndex+2, cFirst); 
  }
}
```

See example file I created: [Show the one's](https://docs.google.com/a/familietuinstra.nl/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ApDwwZxW-IBcdEZFVWtTZHRRUVVzVFdsS1dJRVlKbFE). When the file is opened, it will add another menu item called Sorting. There you can play around and see what happens.